Why is context not passing children elements of React context?
I am using react-router to create 2 pages. The first page is a login page. If the user clicks the google Sign up button created through npm module called google-button, then they get signed into their account and navigated to account route.
I am trying to pass a name through the context hook but am unable to view the name in account page.
I am re-routed to the account page but receive no value for name. This is what I am getting in the console of account page --->

Context value in Account: undefined

I am really stuck and have no idea what to do.
index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from "./App";
import Account from "./components/Account";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />
  },
  {
    path: "/account",
    element: <Account />
  }
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);

App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import GoogleButton from 'react-google-button';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router';

export const UserNameContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
  const name = "Lea";

  const handleClick = () => {
    setUser(!user);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("user value changed");
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserNameContext.Provider value={name}>
      <div>
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <GoogleButton onClick={handleClick} />
        {user ? <Navigate to="/account" /> : "User is Signed Out"}
      </div>
    </UserNameContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;

Account.js file -
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserNameContext } from "../App.js";

const Account = () => {
  const name = useContext(UserNameContext);

  console.log("Context value in Account:", name);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Account page</h1>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Account;


If you would like the UserNameContext context value to be accessible outside the App component's sub-ReactTree then UserNameContext.Provider needs to be rendered higher in the ReactTree.
Suggestion is to move the state and UserNameContext.Provider to the index file and provide the context to the sub-ReactTree rendering the routes and routed components, e.g. App and Account.
Create a provider component to hold and provide the context value:
UserNameProvider
import React, {
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createContext
} from 'react';

export const UserNameContext = createContext();

export useUserNameContext = () => useContext(UserNameContext);

const UserNameProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
  const name = "Lea";

  const handleClick = () => {
    setUser(!user);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("user value changed");
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <UserNameContext.Provider value={{ name, user, handleClick }}>
      {children}
    </UserNameContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserNameProvider;

App
import React from 'react';
import GoogleButton from 'react-google-button';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router';
import { useUserNameContext } from '../path/to/UserNameProvider';

const App = () => {
  const { user, handleClick } = useUserNameContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <GoogleButton onClick={handleClick} />
      {user ? <Navigate to="/account" /> : "User is Signed Out"}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

index.js
Create a layout route component to render the UserNameProvider component and an Outlet for nested routes to render their content into.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from 'react-router-dom';

import UserNameProvider from '../path/to/UserNameProvider';
import App from "./App";
import Account from "./components/Account";

const UserNameProviderLayout = () => (
  <UserNameProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </UserNameProvider>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <UserNameProviderLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <App />
      },
      {
        path: "/account",
        element: <Account />
      }
    ],
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);

Account
import React from 'react';
import { useUserNameContext } from '../path/to/UserNameProvider';

const Account = () => {
  const { name } = useUserNameContext();

  console.log("Context value in Account:", name);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Account page</h1>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Account;


Thank you so much Sir, I was really stuck with this you have solved my query. Thank you very much.
